# SQL Server inner join

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, inner-join

How to choose main table when joining multiple tables using inner join?

A) Should I choose main table depending on its number of columns/rows (For example large main as main table or to keep larger table as join table)?

B) If I choose the table containing column that I use in where condition as main table ,   will there be any performance benefit ?

For example lets say there are 2 tables. Table1 & Table2 . Will there be any performance difference between two solutions given below

Solution 1 :

```
select t1.empid , t1.name , t1.dept , t2.add , t2.city , t2.country
from Table1 t1
inner join Table2 t2 on t2.empid = t1.empid
where t1.year = 2010
```

Solution 2 :

```
select t1.empid , t1.name , t1.dept , t2.add , t2.city , t2.country
from Table2 t2
inner join Table1 t1 on t1.empid = t2.empid 
where t1.year = 2010
```

Comment: You can check the execution plans but I would be very surprised if there was a differnce.

Comment: I don't think it will make any difference.

Comment: Thanks HLGEM & Nilesh for your comments. If I choose large table as main table , will there be any difference? Is there any basic thumb rule for inner join to make it efficient ?

Comment: I tried above experiment(MSSQL) and didn't see any changes in execution plan. However, I observed changes in execution time. When you place table with larger number of records first in your query, it takes more time for execution. With 'where' clause there were no changes in execution plan as well as in execution time.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference. SQL Server will pick "main" table and join type based on table statistics.

Example: 
Table1 contains 5 rows (and only one with year 2010). Table2 contains 10000 rows. 
SQL Server will generate Nested Loops join with Table1 as outer input, Table2 as inner input, to get 1 run over 1000 rows. It will definitely not generate 10000 cycles over 1 row.

You still can get different execution plans for statements above, but only in case if SQL Server will decide that plan should be trivial and will skip the optimization phase (because tables are almost empty, for example).

Answer (score 1):

The main table should be the one that you are using the most columns from, so if you are using table1 with 4 columns and you need to get one column out of table2.